# Is "critical pipe" a proper term for a pipe used in a critically important role?

Tags: terminology

My translation:

> Internal pipe diameter inspection
>
> This kind of inspection is carried out on a by-order basis using a certified gauge (for sizes 40 mm and above) of the go/no go type, with both sides of the pipe subjected to measurement along the length specified in the regulatory documentation. Pipes intended for use in shock-absorbers are inspected using the special instrument called a bore gauge. Instrumental inspection of internal pipe diameter is carried out for **critical pipes** and relies on the use of ultrasonic equipment.

The original Russian phrase is "трубы ответственного назначения" and could be translated as "pipes used in critically important roles (applications)": when a malfunction may lead to injuries, deaths or major industrial accidents, or to the shutdown of the whole plant, with the resulting financial losses.

Is the phrase "critical pipes" a proper choice, or are there some other phrases to signal the same meaning? Would "critical duty pipes" fit?

The word-for-word of the original is "truby (pipes) otvetstvennogo (of high responsibility) naznacheniya (purpose)".

Comment: I suspect the common language will depend on application. Is this pressure piping (for fluids to flow though) or structural piping (for a tubular frame?

Comment: isnt that just an adjective? or is it a term? i dont see any difference from if it were replaced with "important". maybe its like "safety critical"?

Comment: @Ethan48 - I guess it could be either, because the Pervouralsk New Pipe Plant produces a wide range of pipes (or should I say "tubing"?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Critical (meaning 8)](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/critical?s=t): *of essential importance*

"Critical pipes" sounds fine to me, meaning "the ones which are absolutely essential". It doesn't clash with any engineering meaning (which is, I assume, your reason for asking here).

Comment: In an engineering context, especially for pressure/process piping, I think critical would be more likely to mean "The ones that if they failed, would cause the worst consequences" or "The ones which are most likely to fail because they have the least safety margin in their design" or some combination of the two. See "Fracture Critical" or "Slip Critical" for example.